# How to align React bootstrap NavBar to the left

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I've created a React Bootstrap navbar, however, I'm not able to get it aligned to the left.

NavBar code that I'm using:

```
import React from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav, Container, NavDropdown } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function NavBar() {
  return (
    <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">
          My NavBar
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
            <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
                Another action
              </NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Divider />
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">
                Separated link
              </NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
}
```

My App.js code:

```
import React from "react";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";

function App() {

  return (
    <main>
      <NavBar />
   
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is what the NavBar looks like:

[image]

How can I get the Brand "My Nav Bar" to move to the left?

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-galois-g590u1?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove Container. Explanation: Container adds extra padding left and right on large screens.

https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/navbar/#containers